# Problems with Json and searching using for each loop

Tags: php, json

I am using an api that comes back in JSON and in i guess called "pairs".  excuse me if that is the wrong terminology

I am then searching thru looking the json that comes back for a specific user ID.  which happens to be the second of the two pairs.

I am looking to get the balance of the id

so the JSON comes Back like this:

```
{"balance":"104","id":"2264511436216725766"},
{"balance":"100","id:"13430408307535451875"},
{"balance":"160","id":"4496198869167276848"},
```

This is what i am using now:

```
$set="4496198869167276848";
foreach($result['Balances'] as $key=>$value){ 

    $qty =  number_format($value['balance'] / 100000, 4);
    $ID= $value['id'];

    if($ID == $set){

         $sql = "UPDATE $table SET meta_value='$qty' WHERE user_id = '$user' AND meta_key = 'default_total' ";

         if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
              // echo "Record updated successfully";
         } else {
              // echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
          }

         break;
     } else {
            $msg="<strong style='text-decoration:none;color:#289dcc;font-weight:bold'>ERROR !!! It Looks like you do not Have any Shares</strong><br>";
            echo $msg;
                break; 
   }
}
```

well what is happening is it only showing the 1st balance which is 104

I need it to stop once it finds it so i put the  `break;`

without it will show the error message.

Comment: you have missing `"` around `id` in second data of JSON here:- `{"balance":"100","id:"13430408307535451875"},` is it a typo?

Comment: first pair doesn't match the condition, so will go to else condition. 'break' in the else will cause the termination of loop. Remove the 'break' from else condition to continue the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look Here you make mistakes several things

**Explanation**

- at here `if($ID == $set)` than you make update query it is fine. But when you it makes first foreach loop than `$ID != 4496198869167276848` so it is goes to `else` condition and at in `else` condition you put `break` so after first execution it will break that's you only get first balance

So make it like this

```
$set="4496198869167276848";
foreach($result['Balances'] as $key=>$value){ 

    $qty =  number_format($value['balance'] / 100000, 4);
    $ID= $value['id'];

    if($ID == $set){

         $sql = "UPDATE $table SET meta_value='$qty' WHERE user_id = '$user' AND meta_key = 'default_total' ";

         if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
              // echo "Record updated successfully";
         } else {
              // echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
          }
          break;
     } else {
            $msg="<strong style='text-decoration:none;color:#289dcc;font-weight:bold'>ERROR !!! It Looks like you do not Have any Shares</strong><br>";
            echo $msg;
   }
}
```

Just remove break from your `else` condition

And more important thing

**Your mysql query is in danger of sql injection. So try to use bind parameters**

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: thank you that works But it it is sill showing the error.

Comment: it is still the echo  $msg

Comment: Yes it will so you can use `echo $msg` outside the loop